# "Wait" or "waiting"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, nouns

As nouns, are there any specifics situations for the use of each one? Or do they have the same meaning in all cases?

> The **wait** is over.
>
> The **waiting** is over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your examples express equivalent thoughts and both are used, I believe, with equal frequency. `Wait` as a noun has the same meaning as `waiting`, gerund.

---

Of course, not all words as noun and gerund are exactly equivalent, just to confuse things.

> The **run** is over.

Might mean a string of wins is broken

> The **running** is over.

Might mean a race is finished

> The **ticking** is annoying.

Could be a noisy clock **or** uncomfortable pillow cover

> The **tick** is annoying.

Could be that same loud clock **or** a blood-sucking arachnid

<sub>*Sorry about that digression.*</sub>